# MockContentResolver is not found in an Android Test project with separate module

Tags: android, android-testing

I'm trying to setup a test project like is described in the [Android Testing Blueprint](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/tree/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint) but I receive the following NoClassDefFoundError:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.test.mock.MockContentResolver
```

Android Studio resolves this correctly but when running I receive this error.

It's worth to note that I do not have an androidTest configuration on the app project, instead I only have a separate `tests` module with:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.test'
```

I'm running tests like this:

```
 ./gradlew :tests:connectedAndroidTest
```

Test project to reproduce this issue can be found here:
https://github.com/vexdev/android-testing-templates/tree/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint

EDIT: Also asked on [Android Development community](https://plus.google.com/106636663923951797914/posts/PTvUTCP39Gm)

EDIT: Also created following android issue:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200182&thanks=200182&ts=1454489567

Comment: The problem is test code doesn't spread across modules well. The test packages and source code gets built out and doesn't come with packaged binaries when it gets included in the other module. I currently workaround this by copying shared testing dependencies in every module manually, and duplicated testing code in each module. I don't like doing it that way, but hacking up the gradle to keep the test code around is too big a mess at this point. In your case, maybe just stop using a test module and put this in the test source code structure that the gradle plugins are expecting.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, I'm talking of android.test.mock.* package, that should be already included in the test APK but for some reason is not. Workarounds for this would be accepted.
In the meantime I opened an issue on code.google.com (See edit to the post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some android packages are not automatically linked, but you have to explicitly specify them using the `<uses-library>` tag. That is the case with the `android.test` package ([see uses-library docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element.html)), like [@rds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94363/rds) mentioned.

Adding a compile dependency will work if you have `minSdkVersion > =15`, but will add a legacy Maven artifact that has been updated on the Aug 24, 2012 for the last time.

IMHO, it might be a better solution to add the following snippet to the manifest of the test module:

`<application>
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>`

This will tell the system to include the `android.test` package as well, so the `MockContentResolver` will be found by the class loader.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

As @rds said, test package is not part of the framework on the device, therefore you need to include the package.

Seems like com.android.test plugin is not adding those classes, so you can fix it by adding

```
compile 'com.google.android:android-test:4.1.1.4'
```

in your dependencies for the module where you are applying the plugin.

Comment: Suggested workaround works, though I would like to see a proper fix from google.

Comment: The proper fix is to place your test code in `src/test/java`.

Comment: That would be possible if plugin: 'com.android.test' supports test/androidTest, unfortunately it doesn't.
You can see this if you try adding any dependency via testCompile/androidTestCompile.

@rds have you tested your suggestion? Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

The MockContentProvider is not part of the framework, it's only shipped in the SDK for test apks.

> In your Android Studio project, you must store the source files for local unit tests under a specific source directory (`src/test/java`)